# Cannon matrix multiplication in MPI

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I'm trying to implement Cannon's matrix multiplication algorithm in C using MPI and nonblocking communication. I've tried the example code at http://siber.cankaya.edu.tr/ozdogan/GraduateParallelComputing.old/ceng505/node133.html, but I can't get it to work.

It works fine when executed with a single node, but more than that and it's not finishing.

I'm trying to use a randomized 4*4 matrix on 4 nodes. From what I can gather with absolutely no debugging tools aside from printf process with rank 0 finishes executing the function, but other processes get stuck at MPI_Wait on line 68. I'm pretty new to C and parallel programming and can't figure out what's wrong.

EDIT: During debugging I found one incredibly baffling thing - calling MPI_Barrier seems to hang the whole program.

I call MPI_Barrier in main after the multiplication function is completed. To make debugging a little easier i decided to split the function code into parts and separate them with barriers. placing the barrier at the end of main computation loop ( so that every process has to complete one iteration for any process to start the next one ) resulted in the loop not even reaching second iteration.

It seems that when a single process reaches the barrier after non blocking sends/receives and consequent calls to MPI_Wait it causes other processes to wait indefinitely and never reach the barrier.

Here's an example code:

```
void generateArray(int * vector, int size){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i ++){
    vector[i] = rand()%10 + 1;
}
}

int test_size = 4;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
MPI_Init (&argc, &argv); 

int comm_size, myrank;
int my2drank, mycoords[2]; 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_size); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);


MPI_Request requests[4];
MPI_Status status[4];

MPI_Comm comm_2d;
int dims[2], periods[2];
dims[0] = dims[1] = sqrt(comm_size);
periods[0] = periods[1] = 1; 
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dims, periods, 1, &comm_2d);

int sizelocal = test_size/dims[0];

srand(time(NULL));
int a[sizelocal*sizelocal], b[sizelocal*sizelocal];
generateArray(a, sizelocal*sizelocal);                              
generateArray(b, sizelocal*sizelocal);

MPI_Comm_rank(comm_2d, &my2drank); 
MPI_Cart_coords(comm_2d, my2drank, 2, mycoords); 

int uprank, downrank, leftrank, rightrank; 
MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -1, &rightrank, &leftrank);
MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, -1, &downrank, &uprank); 

int *buffersA[2], *buffersB[2];

buffersA[0] = a; 
buffersA[1] = (int *)malloc(sizelocal*sizelocal*sizeof(int)); 
buffersB[0] = b; 
buffersB[1] = (int *)malloc(sizelocal*sizelocal*sizeof(int));

int shiftsource, shiftdest; 
MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -mycoords[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest); 
MPI_Sendrecv_replace(buffersA[0], sizelocal*sizelocal, MPI_INT,shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status[0]); 

MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, -mycoords[1], &shiftsource, &shiftdest); 
MPI_Sendrecv_replace(buffersB[0], sizelocal*sizelocal, MPI_INT,shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status[0]);

printf("Rank %d at point 1\n", my2drank);    

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
    printf("Rank %d started iteration %d\n", my2drank, i);
    MPI_Isend(buffersA[i%2], sizelocal*sizelocal, MPI_INT,leftrank, 1, comm_2d, &requests[0]); 
    MPI_Isend(buffersB[i%2], sizelocal*sizelocal, MPI_INT,uprank, 1, comm_2d, &requests[1]); 
    MPI_Irecv(buffersA[(i+1)%2], sizelocal*sizelocal, MPI_INT,rightrank, 1, comm_2d, &requests[2]); 
    MPI_Irecv(buffersB[(i+1)%2], sizelocal*sizelocal, MPI_INT,downrank, 1, comm_2d, &requests[3]);

    MPI_Waitall(4, requests, status);
    printf("Rank %d stopped waiting in iteration %d\n", my2drank, i);
    MPI_Barrier(comm_2d);
}

printf("Rank %d at point 2\n", my2drank);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Rank 0 at point 1
Rank 0 started iteration 0
Rank 1 at point 1
Rank 1 started iteration 0
Rank 2 at point 1
Rank 2 started iteration 0
Rank 3 at point 1
Rank 3 started iteration 0
Rank 0 stopped waiting in iteration 0
```

Comment: Did you make sure that your nodes can communicate with each other? Try running a simple ping-pong example.

Comment: Yes, they're communicating perfectly. As I mentioned in the edit MPI_Barrier seems to cause the issue, but it's required. Would it help if I pasted my whole code to pastebin and added the link?

Comment: Whole code, not so much. Create a minimal working example and paste that in the question.

Comment: I've been trying to create that example code, but, to my surprise, it works. I've recreated a similar topology and similar communication and it simply works. And yet the code from the link included in the question does not work. The best I can do is paste the main in which I'm calling the function basically copied from the link.

Comment: I finally managed to create an example not working code, it's now pasted in the question. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry to double post (again), but I finally managed to pinpoint the problem - it's the initial shift. In my example code, in the original algorithm and in my modified version. After I commented it out the program suddenly works and successfully reaches the end. However, I've got no idea why the initial shift is causing all those problems. It's not an issue with MPI_Sendrecv, in my modified version I replaced it with Isends and Irecvs.